# How to install Bundler to @global gemset under RVM and is it a correct way

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, bundler

I am on OS X (if it matters).

If I install a Ruby using RVM, it will install Bundler by default to **@global** gemset

Let say I want a different version of the bundler. I assumed that all I needed to do is to execute

```
gem install bundler --version <SomeVersion>
```

However, this will install bundler to **default** gemset and RVM doesn't set a PATH to it.

As result, if I type `bundler` it will still launch a bundler which was installed with Ruby into @global

Two questions:

- How can I install bundler to @global gemset.
- Is this correct pattern to install bundler into @global gemset or I am missing something

Answer (score 10):

This is how you can install bundler in the global gemset:

```
rvm @global do gem install bundler
```

as a practice, I don't see any issue, since bundler is never part of the gemfile in any case.

One glitch to note, if you have projects running multiple rails and ruby version (as old as 1.8.7 and rails 2.x) using newer bundler is not backwards compatible, so you'll be forced to use multiple bundler versions.

Comment: That's simply not true, `bundler` is listed in the [Redmine Gemfile](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/trunk/Gemfile).